# How do I properly set up hooks on a remote that is specified via the file:// protocol?

Tags: windows, git, hook, git-post-receive

Say I've got an upstream repo (`origin`) that was added with

```
git remote add origin file:////upstream.host/repo.git
```

The `repo.git` is acually a windows shared folder where I and my dev colleagues have r/w access assigned.

Now, I want to set up a `post-receive` hook on `upstream.host` that notifies [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org) about freshly pushed revisions for [automatic ticket updating](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CommitTicketUpdater). Basically, this is done by calling an executable on `upstream.host` that does some work in the database there.

However, I notified that the hook for some reason doesn't work.
So I've set up the hook to print everything she's doing to `D:/temp/post-receive.log` and issued a `git push` in order to trigger the hook.

When I looked into `D:/temp` on `upstream.host`, there was no logfile created.
Then, another question of me came into mind: https://superuser.com/questions/974337/when-i-run-a-git-hook-in-a-repo-on-a-network-share-which-binaries-are-used.
When actually the binaries of my machine are used for executing the hook, maybe also the **paths** of my machine are used. I looked into `D:/temp` and voilá, here we have the `post-receive.log`.

I traced the `pwd` to the logfile and it is not `D:/repos/repo.git` (what I expected) but actually is `//upstream.host/repo.git`. Obviously the whole hook is executed in the context of the pusher's machine and not in the context of the repo machine (`upstream.host`).

This is no problem for *me* since I have admin access to the remote machine and could use administrative shares in order to get my hook going (i.e. `\\upstream.host\D$\repos\repo.git` etc). But this **is** an issue for my colleagues since they are plain users and no roots.

How do I set up my `post-receive` hook properly so that it works as expected?

How do I force my hook to be entirely run on the remote machine without using anything from my machine?

Do I really have to implement a real server hosting my repo? Or are there other ways that don't need a server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a `post-receive` hook is run after receiving data on the machine that is hosting the repository.

now the machine that is "hosting the repository" is *not* the file-server where the actual `packed-refs` and other git database files are stored. (this file-server could be anything from a redundant cloud-based storage appliance to any old NAS-enabled "network disk").

Instead it is the machine that runs the "git frontend" (that is, the git commands that actually interact with the *database*).

Now you are using a "network share" to host your (remote) git repository. For your computer (the *client*), this is just another disk device (like your floppy) and the git on your *client* will happily store database-files there, and run any hooks. But this is your computer, since it is being told to run the *remote* locally - simply because the `file://` protocol does mean "local".

Btw, the fact that your remote is named `upstream.host` is meaningless: this name is only there for *you* to keep track of multiple remotes, but it could be called `thursday.next`  instead.

So there is no way to run any script on the file-server that happens to store some files names `pack-refs` and similar.

If you want to have a *git server* to run hooks for you, you must have a *git server* first. Even worse: if you want a git server on machineX to run scripts on machineX, you must install a git server on machineX first.

The good news: there is no need to "implement a real server". Just install a pre-existing one. You will find docuementation about that in the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols), but for starters it's basically enough to have `git` (for interaction with the database) and `sshd` (for secure communication via the network; and for calling `git` when appropriate) installed.

Finally: i'm actually quite glad that you need to have software (e.g. a server) running on the *remote end* to execute code there. Just imagine what it would mean if copying some html files to your USB disk would suddenly spawn a web server out of thin air. Not to think of w32-virusses breeding happily on my linux NAS...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I already know that a hook gets executed in the context of my local machine. I'd be interested in a *creative* way how to notify my trac installation on machine B that there were just pushed some new commits...

Comment: seems like the *creative way* was stripped from your original question. Instead I read "Do I really have to implement a real server hosting my repo?" which I tried to answer.

Comment: While this answer is not what I was hoping for, it seems like the only way to run a separate server. Thank you for your contribution!